# Angular: Check if element has a class and add a class to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, ng-class

How can I check with Angular if a DOM element has a class and then add a class to another element?

My Template:

```
<div class="d-table">
  <ui-switch class="d-table-cell">
    <span class="switch">
      <small></small>
    </span>
  </ui-switch>
  <span class="d-table-cell"> 
    sign in
  </span>
</div>
```

If the span with the class ***switch*** has also the class ***checked***, then the color of the text between the span element with the class ***d-table-cell*** should be black, otherwise the color should be gray.

No problem with jQuery, but I want to do it the right Angular way :)

Comment: why you cannot use jquery here, with angular why you are making your dom complicated??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.gray {
  color:gray;
}
.black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table">
 <span class="switch" #switch>
      <small></small>
    </span>
  <span class="d-table-cell" [ngClass]="switch.classList.contains('checked')  ? 'gray' : 'black'"> 
    sign in
  </span>
</div>
```

We can create template reference variables and can directly access them in the template to get attributes, classes and etc. #switch is a template reference variable

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utcvxr)

Answer (score 2):

1. step: create a template ref for the main element like this:
   HTML:

in the corresponding component:

```
@ViewChild('switchSpan') switchSpanElement:ElementRef;
```

After this, you can check the classlist of the said element like this:

```
 if(switchSpanElement:ElementRef.nativeElement.classList.contains('checked')) {
    ...
  }
```

2. step: create a boolean variable in the component, that you can access in the template as well (==don't make it private).

`isSwitchChecked = false;`

and you can make it check whether the class was added when change detecion runs ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018891/angular2-detect-if-element-in-template-view-has-class/38019099), [syntax here](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck))

```
   class <yourComponent> implements DoCheck
    ...
    ngDoCheck() {
      this.isSwitchChecked =  witchSpanElement:ElementRef.nativeElement.classList.contains('checked');
    }
```

you can then bind that boolean variable in the template to add a class to the said span:

```
 <span class="d-table-cell" [ngClass]={'some-class':isSwitchChecked}> 
    sign in
  </span>
```

and you can define a class in css:

```
.some-class{
   background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Angular way would be to avoid, if possible, direct, low-level DOM manipulation. Tie the `checked` class to some model, and tie the `d-table-cell`'s class to the same model. Like that:

```
<div class="d-table">
  <ui-switch class="d-table-cell" [class.checked]="someVariable">
    <span class="switch">
      <small></small>
    </span>
  </ui-switch>
  <span class="d-table-cell" [class.active]="someVariable"> 
    sign in
  </span>
</div>
```

and in TS

```
someVariable: boolean;
```

Maybe tie `someVariable` to an `ngModel` of some input, or whatever logic should dictate whether the switch is checked or not.